# Como Soluciono el Error de Android ==> "Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

Me aparece el Siguiente Error:

**Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.**

El siguiente Error continua apareciendo luego de haber instalado el "HAXM" de Intel como el pluguin que se encuentra por defecto en el IDE de Android, ademas de haber Activado la Virtualizacion en la Bios y actualizar el emulador y los SDK Tools, y Platform Tools. No hallo forma de Solucionar ese Error y los demás Errores.

Desconozco el motivo por el cual siguen apareciendo. En General he "INTENTADO_TODO" lo posible y la información hallada no es suficientemente precisa. Solicito cordialmente su ayuda para solucionar dicho percance ademas de conocer su motivo.

Y el procedimiento que se debe seguir para arreglarlo.

===============================================================================================

1) Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

2) Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture

3)  Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID

4)  Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

5)  Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

6)  Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

7)  Emulator: C:\Users\xyyydz1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system- 
 x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

8)  Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\xyyydz1.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

9) Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

10) Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

11) Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object

13) Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

14) Emulator: Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución provisional para seguir funcionando mientras los chicos de Android Studio no saquen una actualización, la dejo en la imagen de abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias, compañero Manuel la verdad es que estaba bastante perdido, pero es decir, que es por una actualizacion pendiente en android, que surgen estos errorers o porque motivo adicional puede ser?. Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: No funciona ni haciendo WIPEDATA